# How can I remove \ (backslash)?

Tags: go, backslash

I use gin web framework and this is data in redis

```
[
  {
    "Score": 12,
    "Member": "{"empname":"DDDDDDDD","empid":20}"
  },
  {
    "Score": 5,
    "Member": "{"empname":"Dixya Lhyaho","empid":10}"
  }
]
```

after fetch from  redis , why return like this

```
[
  {
    "Score": 12,
    "Member": "{\"empname\":\"DDDDDDDD\",\"empid\":20}"
  },
  {
    "Score": 5,
    "Member": "{\"empname\":\"Dixya Lhyaho\",\"empid\":10}"
  }
]
```

How to remove backslash in json (member only) ?

---

https://go.dev/play/p/QtaapMgfjtn

**done.**

Comment: sounds like you want to decode the JSON. https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.18.2

Comment: Please post code as text. Screenshots are not readable e.g. by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend you to use json.NewDecoder() and then convert your struct by using the Decode() method. This is much more faster than Unmarshal.
You can check on detail the json documentation that Garr left you as a comment.
Anyway, how are you converting this struct to json? So we can help you better

Comment: now , I have added new information.

Comment: So I think you should be using Redis as a key value or list database instead of saving a JSON, on scale you will endup having a lot of issues encoding/decoding constantly. But, If this is just an example to learn Go or whatever this is how I will do it:
https://go.dev/play/p/QtaapMgfjtn

Regards!